# In Rails Im getting the error 'instance variable @cached_changed_attributes not defined' when trying to add an edit link for a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im just trying to add the edit link for a `product` record in a list of products like this :

```
<td class='textcenter'><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_dash_product_path(product), class: 'label label-warning' %></td>
```

In here im getting an error like this :

```
instance variable @cached_changed_attributes not defined
```

I don't have such an instance variable and haven't even added caching to the app. What might be the problem?

The full stack trace, template files : https://gist.github.com/THPubs/7aae392ea3a2464c8638

The product model :

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: products
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  code           :string
#  name           :string
#  description    :text
#  price          :money
#  category_id    :integer
#  subcategory_id :integer
#  qty            :integer
#  sold           :integer          default("0")
#  vendor_id      :integer
#  brand_id       :integer
#  helpfultips    :text
#  discount       :integer
#  discountend    :datetime
#  discountterms  :text
#  material       :string
#  arrangedby     :string
#  published      :date
#  model          :string
#  weight         :integer
#  weightunit     :string
#  warranty       :string
#  features       :text
#  specs          :text
#  ingredients    :text
#  included       :text
#  return         :text
#  approved       :boolean          default("false")
#  slug           :string
#  featuredimg    :integer          default("0")
#  created_at     :datetime         not null
#  updated_at     :datetime         not null
#
```

Comment: Post the entire stack trace, including the definition of the Product model.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti sorry The entire stack trace : https://gist.github.com/THPubs/7aae392ea3a2464c8638

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Just updated the gist with all three files

Comment: You need to post also the Product model definition. Moreover, it looks like the issue is somehow also dependent on friendly_id. You will need to start taking pieces away and debug the stack trace, it may be an edge case or incompatibility between some of the gems you are using.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Just added the product model structure :-) hope that's what you meant

Comment: No, you posted the schema, not the model. You need the Ruby code of your model to debug the stacktrace, the schema is useless.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Ah just included the model in the gist also

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Ok I got it fixed! Just changed `edit_dash_product_path(product)` to `edit_dash_product_path(product.id)` :-) Seems to be a problem in feidnly_id. Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it fixed! As @Simone pointed out in the comments, the problem is with `friendly_id`. This happened after updating my gems. `friendly_id` had issues with the new gems (Most probably activerecord).

### The solution

To solve the problem I had to upgrade `friendly_id` to the latest beta version by adding this to the Gemfile :

```
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2.0.beta.1'
```

Not the best fix but will work for now.